# How to prevent content in iframe from being dragged outside in developer tools

Tags: html, iframe, access-control, google-developers-console

I am using an iframe in another iframe to add watermarks to an embeded video player.

The issue I am having is that from the developer tools, it's possible to drag the embeded player iframe outside of the iframe container with watermarks.

Here is a before and after:

I am not sure how to disable this feature, I wasn't able to drag the content inside the embeded player's iframe, so it appears to be possible. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I figured out the issue is that you can move the iframe content around if the origin is the same. This issue only presents if testing on the same domain.

Comment: You can't prevent people from mucking with developer tools.